# How to install and configure sphinx on wamp and phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, sphinx

I am building a search server I want to use sphinx Search server, but I am new with it
i search the net but i didn't find a good solution.

1. How to install sphinx in wamp?
2. Is there any way to manage it with phpmyadmin?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont install into wamp. Wamp is on windows. So you install Sphinx on windows. But you could access sphinx from an application running in Wamp. 
   Search the net, there are tutorials for installing Sphinx on Windows machines.
2. Thats like asking can you control your hi-fi using the TV remote control. While it might be possible, and somethings are similar between the two. Really is a different thing altogether. 
   In general sphinx doesnt need much management, beyond setting it up in the config file.